# roleAssignment with current user id

Tags: azure, azure-devops, arm, rbac, azure-bicep

I'm using Azure AD app registration principles to deploy resources via Azure Resource Manager to deploy via Pipelines.
During the deployment I need to set some permissions to the deployment user to ensure it has enough permission to - for example - upload files.
As I'm using different principles, and I'm not managing those in the code, I would like to know if there is a way to reference the "current user-principals - ID" during the deployment.

Something like:

```
deployment().properties.xx
```

or

```
environment()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-deployment
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/roleassignments?tabs=bicep

Otherwise, I would need to inject this information via parameter, I think. I could get that information by script - or there is a variable even present from azure dev ops.
Any ideas, help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you will have to inject the details. are you using az cli or powershell to deploy ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it's not possible to get the objectId of the user deploying the template... we do have a backlog item for it.

Comment: any news about this feature? I also need it to create keys in a KeyVaultduring a deployment process.

Comment: We have it on the backlog - no specific date yet...

Comment: Is this backlog-item public? Can you link it so we can reference it in our documentation?

Comment: It is not public

Comment: We would like this feature too @bmoore-msft. We want our ADO Service Connection principal user set secrets in our keyvault.

Comment: Will be very useful