# How to get the objecid of user running bicep script for keyvault accessPolicies on initial create

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am trying to set up a bicep file to create a KeyVault and wanted to know if there was a function or method to get the user/owner objectid so when I was setting up the keyvault one access policy would be populated? I see when I create one manually my objectid ends up being the objectid, can I get this programmatically?

```
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: '${namePrefix}keyvault'
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        objectId: //is there any way to get the person running the script or subscription owner?
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        permissions: {
          secrets: [
            'all'
          ]
          certificates: [
            'all'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    enabledForDeployment: true
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    enabledForDiskEncryption: true
    enableRbacAuthorization: false
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: 90
  }
}
```

I see that there are certain functions available like:

- subscription()
- resourceGroup()

...and was hoping there might be one for this purpose. I looked through the [bicep documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/) but was having trouble finding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per august 2022, this is not supported, there are few related on github:

- [How to Reference an Azure AD User by UPN](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/645)
- [Scope function: Azure Client ID](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4959).

Also According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150997/roleassignment-with-current-user-id) there is an internal backlog item to track this feature.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping to get. It seems like the current user would be important in some of these scenarios.

Comment: For the moment you could always use az cli or powershell command to get the current user/service principal logged in